# differences between Helvetica Neue and Monument Grotesk

Tags: fonts

I usually can spot at least a few difference between Helvetica (or Helvetica Neue) and another font. The a and r are usual suspects but I am struggling to see any difference at all between Monument Grotesk https://abcdinamo.com/typefaces/monument-grotesk and Helvetica or Helvetica Neue. Is there any notable difference ?

Comment: [Comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiggi.png). I didn't include every single character in there because at least the trial of Monument Grotesk pretty much ends there.

Comment: thanks a lot!  so there is basically almost no difference right?

Comment: I mean... anyone can see that there is a slight difference but also, it does depend on who you ask and what the goal is... Ask a worldwide company if it's ok to use this font Monument Grotesk that is basically the same as the font they use Helvetica Neue, they'll likely say no. Ask your parents if there is any difference between Arial and Helvetica Neue and they'll likely say it's exactly the same font.

Comment: One very obvious difference is the [number 1](https://imgur.com/a/35b0EAh), in the regular (non-italic) version.

Comment: @Joonas, why don't you add an answer so the OP can accept and this question won't pop up for eternity? 

Comment: @BillyKerr well spotted

Comment: @Joonas feel free to transform your comment in a reply! p.s. why would a company say no ?  I usually see at least some differences. I read (https://www.typewolf.com/monument-grotesk)  that the closest font to Monoment Grotesk is Neue Haas Grotesk (the original Helvetica)

Comment: Many people here, some mods included, keep saying answers can be too short, no matter how correct they might be. If I post a link to a single image they will lose their sh*t, so I'd rather not. — There could be many reasons why a big company cares more than a smaller company, but one could be that they have paid a lot for brand identity, so there's no point diverging from it... Even if the font is nearly identical and you wouldn't know the difference without a direct comparison. Also, there wouldn't really be much of a point to use a different font.

Comment: @Joonas thanks for your explanation :) I think you should really copy all this into an answer, it is more than just 1 image ..but up to you :)

Comment: The principal difference is that ALL terminals (of letters like s, e G), where Helvetica is horizontal, are not horizontal in Monument Grotesk. It's a halfway house between Helvetica and Arial.

Comment: @AndrewLeach from the comparison I see no difference in the s e or G. The only difference I could see is the number 1

Comment: @devnull I suggest you look again, enlarging the image. The letters are clearly different.